# View images in a Zoom chat at full-res by default?

Tags: pictures, preview, zoom-meeting

I use Zoom for work and we frequently send screenshots between ourselves.
However, Zoom's image previewer loads these (usually relatively large) images as highly compressed, blurry previews, even at 100% magnification level in the preview.
The images can be viewed at full-res when downloaded from Zoom.

**Is there a way to have Zoom show images at their full resolution?**